# Automate updating of Finland GIS data, cadastral, buildings, roads

Tags: update, finland

I am downloading data for the free versions of cadastrals, roads and buildings from open API but I haven't found any way to update the data.

Is anyone here familiar with how the Finnish gov delivers their data?

Is there some kind of service where I can get data that's been updated after a certain time, like incremental updates or do I need to download everything all over again when I want to update?

Comment: There seems to be a service for updating just the changes files https://www.maanmittauslaitos.fi/en/e-services/open-data-file-download-service/open-data-file-updating-service-interface. However, that works only with the file based download services, not with the APIs. Maybe you must download everything from the API, and try to find if data has persistent identifiers and some attribute that tells the last update date if you want to update just the changed features in your own system.

Comment: If this is open data then I think questions about how it is delivered should be asked at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.